# importing pygrib in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygrib

In spite encountering no errors in pygrib installation, I encountered the following error when importing pygrib:

```
>>> import pygrib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /python/python-2.7.13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygrib.so: undefined symbol: __svml_round2_mask
```

Any advice on what could be causing this "undefined symbol" error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined symbol errors are usually caused by one of two things:

- incorrect linking during the build process, or
- a mismatch between the environment used to build the binary or library, and the environment in which it is being run.

### Incorrect linking

If you are building the pygrib module itself, make sure that the required library dependencies are being properly linked, and in the right order. Based on the missing symbol name, `__svml_round2_mask`, I'd guess your `pygrib.so` was compiled with the Intel `icc` C compiler and needs to be linked to the math library containing the SVML (Short Vector Math Library) functions. It's difficult to get more specific without knowing more details of your build environment, but for example, on linux, both `icc` and `gcc` (which both call GNU `ld` for linking) need to have that math library specified on their command line, and it needs to come *after* the binary or library that is calling it.

### Evironment mismatch

If pygrib is not being built by you (either explicitly, or as part of a `pip` or `conda` install command), then you probably have an environment mismatch. This happens when the `pygrib.so` you downloaded was built against different libraries than the ones you have installed. Ideally, all Python binary packages would be built against a very vanilla set of libraries (e.g. the "manylinux1" container for linux wheels) so that they will run on most systems, but sometimes specialized and performance-critical packages need to be built with particular optimizations or against uncommon libraries. If those optimizations or libraries don't match between the build system and the system on which the resulting package is install, the `undefined symbol` error can be the result.

One way to minimize the occurrence of this is to not mix-and-match package repositories where possible. That is, if you're using Anaconda, only pull packages from Anaconda. I know, not always possible, right?

If you're on linux, it is sometimes possible to figure out where the mismatch is by using the `ldd` command, for example:

`$ ldd -r /python/python-2.7.13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygrib.so`

You'll see a bunch of undefined symbols starting with `Py` or `_Py`--ignore those, they're supplied by Python itself. But in amongst those, you'll hopefully discover which particular library is needing `__svml_round2_mask`. Look at its full path carefully, and the full paths of the other libraries listed, and this might suggest where the mismatch came from.

### Other suggestions

- Including more specifics in your question, such as your OS and how you installed `pygrib` and its dependencies, might enable us to offer more specific advice.
- If the title of your question were more specific, it could attract more attention.
- Have you tried other `pygrib` packages? Conda-forge lists several; one of them might match your system.
- Have you tried the `python-eccodes` module instead? It seems to be the recommended successor to pygrib.

Good luck, I hope something in here helps!

Comment: This advice really helped! Thanks a lot. You diagnosed the situation well. I was using different compilers when installing pygrib so it failed. Basically, I had to set the environment and compile both python and gribapi at the same time. By the way, eventually I didn't use gribapi and installed eccodes instead. Fortunately, it also has gribapi.